# Removing empty and whitespace values from an array (not array_filter)

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I seem to be hitting a wall when it comes to removing empty values in my array.

I have the following array:

```
key:0 value: 

key:1 value:type

key:3 value:gear

key:4 value: 

key:5 value:rarity
```

As you can see, Key `0`, and Key `4` are both empty (or filled with a space).

I have tried the following, but it doesn't appear to have worked:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if ($value == ' ' || $value=='' || $value==' ' || empty($value)) { unset($array[$key]); }
    echo 'key:'.$key.' value:'.$value.'</br></br>';
}
```

and even tried it in 2 foreach loops just to be sure, but still nothing.

Comment: Why no `array_filter` ?

Comment: is there an echo in here? *lol!* edit: not anymore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ninja edit ftw ;)

Comment: @castis *lmho!*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in the question, I tried it but it didn't work either, unless I did it wrong? I tried array_filter($array) and also array_filter($array, ' ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues: First you're not calling `continue` even if you unset the array key, meaning that you still print the value. Second - you can easily use `trim` to remove any whitespace that would fubar the comparison.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value) || !trim($value)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        continue;
    }

    echo 'key:' . $key . ' value:' . $value . '</br></br>';
}
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a pint of the finest beer. That has worked. Thank you very much.

It left the first value a empty, but the rest have gone... Why would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Let's not just rush to the "just do this" answer.  Here is what you tried:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a09ae0a14ccf0f5f36f350c9e71d7c8ee0a9605b))

```
$array=[0=>'',1=>'type',3=>'gear',4=>' ',5=>'rarity'];
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if ($value == ' ' || $value=='' || $value==' ' || empty($value)) { unset($array[$key]); }
    echo 'key:'.$key.' value:'.$value."\n";
}
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if ($value == ' ' || $value=='' || $value==' ' || empty($value)) { unset($array[$key]); }
    echo 'key:'.$key.' value:'.$value."\n";
}
```

It is doing what you asked it to do.  The first loop unsets the unwanted elements AND prints the keys & values assigned to the "copy" of `$array` that `foreach()` "writes" & iterates.  The second loop writes & iterates a new "copy" of `$array` (which was previously modified by the first loop) and you can see that the *empty-ish* elements are now gone.

Output:

```
key:0 value:        # unset $array[$key] and display $value (these are different entities
key:1 value:type
key:3 value:gear
key:4 value: 
key:5 value:rarity
key:1 value:type    # you see elements [0] and [4] are removed as intended
key:3 value:gear
key:5 value:rarity
```

Now, for the "Do this" part... You have several options.  Here are a few:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba8e2b22793e970a1ad16e6f7691927057f9e9be))

```
$array=[0=>'',1=>'type',3=>'gear',4=>' ',5=>'rarity'];

var_export(array_filter($array,function($v){return strlen(trim($v));}));  // professional grade: uses the function specifically designed to perform this function and the process will be instantly understood by future devs that read your code

var_export(preg_grep('/\S/',$array));  // A regular expression filter. Regex solutions should only be used when other methods will not suffice.  For this reason, this method is ill-advised

var_export(preg_grep('/^\s*$/',$array,PREG_GREP_INVERT));  // A regular expression filter (inverted pattern filteration). Regex solutions should only be used when other methods will not suffice.  For this reason, this method is ill-advised

foreach($array as $k=>$v){                    // possibly the fastest method, I didn't test, but it is also the most verbose and less descriptive as a technique
    if(!strlen(trim($v))){unset($array[$k]);}
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'type',
  3 => 'gear',
  5 => 'rarity',
)array (
  1 => 'type',
  3 => 'gear',
  5 => 'rarity',
)array (
  1 => 'type',
  3 => 'gear',
  5 => 'rarity',
)array (
  1 => 'type',
  3 => 'gear',
  5 => 'rarity',
)
```

Now the most important piece of advice to give you from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array()
> - (an empty array)
> - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

This "greedy" default behavior is used by `empty()` and `array_filter()` and can really throw a wrench into your task if you are unaware.  This is why in my suggested methods, I write a custom filter condition and in the foreach loop, I replace `empty()` with a `strlen()` call.

Comment: @DisplayName ...actually, what are you doing in your project?  Do you need to modify the array or just _not_ echo certain elements?  I am assuming that you are wanting to modify the array and that you are only echoing to demonstrate your failed method. If you are merely echoing the keys and values, then `unset()` is unnecessary.